# Server between our office network and the internet, as wireless router and ssh tunnel

Tags: dhcp, wifi, ssh-tunnel

We have a small office network that today is behind a normal router connecting us to the internet.

We have a web based system on the internet and we have some admin tools on it that we want to lock to our office IP.

But we still want to be able to access them when we're not at the office.

So I'm thinking that we get a small server for the office that we configure to be both a wireless router and ssh server, that we can tunnel to when we're not at the office and access our admin tools.

Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ssh is one option. A VPN would be another. Traditional port forwarding is a third. Generally speaking, shopping questions like this are off topic as they tend to be too subjective. If you have any specific questions please feel free to ask them.

Is the ssh solution good?: Maybe. It might do what you want.

is there something better?: a VPN comes to mind, but 'better' is too subjective until we know exactly what it is you hope to accomplish.

---

additionally, you might consider investing in a nice (See: supports VPN) consumer grade wireless router and using it to handle wireless, DHCP, and the VPN access. This will he a much cheaper approach than buying a full 'server'. Capacity planning is on you though.